# Windows Sandbox dependency

Tags: dependencies, sandbox, ghidra, windows-sandbox

I am trying to run Ghidra(malware analysis software) inside Windows Sandbox. I brought Ghidra over to the Sandbox environment by creating a shared directory between the Sandbox and the host using .wsb file. When I try to run Ghidra inside the Sandbox, a cmd prompt pop up that says

> Java runtime not found.  Please refer to the Ghidra Installation Guide's Troubleshooting section.
> Press any key to continue . . .

Ghidra depends on JDK 11. I tried bringing JDK 11 installer to the shared folder and running it inside the Sandbox Environment but then windows installer says

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify ... (redacted)

It seems like other people run other applications just fine in Sandbox environment. How could I set up the dependencies of applications that I want to run inside Windows Sandbox?

Comment: Have you tried having the configuration file (wsb) download and install JDK 11? In other words don't use the JDK installer on the host, install JDK 11 cleanly by downloading from the internet within the sandbox.